# Validation on Lookup

Tags: formula, validation, validation-rule

I am stuck with a simple validation rule on my lookup. I just don't want anyone to edit my lookup field on new/edit  record. When I try using the below formula  suggested by someone on success community, it works fine on new record but fails to work when I edit record. Also on new record, when it gives me an error after I change my lookup, I try to retain my older value but still it doesn't allow me to save. Below is the formula:

```
AND( NOT( 
ISBLANK(Lookup__c ) 
), Lookup__c = PRIORVALUE(Lookup__c )
```

What's wrong with this formula?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For "New" record, I assume the lookup is pre-populated and you don't want the user to change the default value. There is no way for you to block the change at this stage since the record is not created yet. You can validate that the value can not be blank.

During "Edit", yes, you can block the change.

The sample formula like below:

```
OR(
ISCHANGED(Lookup__c),
ISBLANK(Lookup__c) 
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the rule, it tells the system when to throw an error. And you're telling the system it should do so when the `Lookup__c` is equal to the old value. In other words, when it didn't change! You need to flip your equality operator!

```
AND(
    NOT(ISBLANK(Lookup__c))
    Lookup__c != PRIORVALUE(Lookup__c)
)
```